# Set WooCommerce country with Javascript, wait for state field update, then set a specific state

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

I am setting the country select menu on page load with Javascript:

```
$('#billing_country').val(billing_country);
```

I have to then trigger the update, because we are not using standard form elements (with spans, divs, placeholders, etc.):

```
$('#billing_country').trigger('change');
```

That much works.

However, since changing the country causes the state select menu to change, my attempt to set the state does not work, I assume because it is happening too fast. How can I detect when the state select menu has updated following a country select menu update, so that I can set it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make the change on `country_to_state_changed` event. This one is triggered when country is changed and after the code replaces the

```
$(document.body).on('country_to_state_changed', function(){
      $('#billing_state').val('CO').trigger('change');
});
```

Here is a great list of javascript events triggered on the WooCommerce frontend:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/list-of-js-events-in-the-woocommerce-frontend

Comment: I did not know those events existed, perfect!